# How tf.data.experimental.group_by_window() operates in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to understand the tf.data.experimental.group_by_window() method in Tensorflow 2 but I have some difficulties.

For a reproducible example I use the one presented in the documentation:

```
components = np.arange(100).astype(np.int64)
dataset20 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(components)
dataset20 = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.group_by_window(key_func=lambda x: x%2, reduce_func=lambda _,\
                                                          els: els.batch(10), window_size=100))

i = 0

for elem in dataset20:

    print('i is {0}\n'.format(i))

    print('elem is {0}'.format(elem.numpy()))

    i += 1

    print('\n--------------------------------\n')

i is 0

elem is [0 2 4 6 8]

--------------------------------

i is 1

elem is [1 3 5 7 9]

--------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the confusion may be that the output doesn't correspond to the example code. The actual output from this:

```
components = np.arange(100).astype(np.int64)
dataset20 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(components)
dataset20 = dataset20.apply(tf.data.experimental.group_by_window(key_func=lambda x: x%2, reduce_func=lambda _,els: els.batch(10), window_size=100))
for i, d in enumerate(dataset20): 
    print(i, d.numpy())
```

is

```
0 [ 0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18]
1 [20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38]
2 [40 42 44 46 48 50 52 54 56 58]
3 [60 62 64 66 68 70 72 74 76 78]
4 [80 82 84 86 88 90 92 94 96 98]
5 [ 1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19]
6 [21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39]
7 [41 43 45 47 49 51 53 55 57 59]
8 [61 63 65 67 69 71 73 75 77 79]
9 [81 83 85 87 89 91 93 95 97 99]
```

As described in the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/group_by_window), the `key func` separates the data into groups with associated key values. In the example the `key func` separates the data [0, 99] into even and odd groups. The `reduce_func` then operates on the key, group pairs to produce another dataset. Note though that `reduce_func` only operates on groups of data no greater than `window_size`. In the example, the window size is greater than the two group sizes (100 vs 50 elements), so has no effect and all evens are given in batches of 10 followed by all odds. If `window size` is changed to a value less than 50 then it does have an effect. For example, if the window size is changed to 5 and also the batching is moved to outside the `group_by_window` function:

```
dataset20 = dataset20.apply(tf.data.experimental.group_by_window(key_func=lambda x: x%2, reduce_func=lambda _, els: els, window_size=5)).batch(10)
```

then the following output is produced:

```
0 [0 2 4 6 8 1 3 5 7 9]
1 [10 12 14 16 18 11 13 15 17 19]
2 [20 22 24 26 28 21 23 25 27 29]
3 [30 32 34 36 38 31 33 35 37 39]
4 [40 42 44 46 48 41 43 45 47 49]
5 [50 52 54 56 58 51 53 55 57 59]
6 [60 62 64 66 68 61 63 65 67 69]
7 [70 72 74 76 78 71 73 75 77 79]
8 [80 82 84 86 88 81 83 85 87 89]
9 [90 92 94 96 98 91 93 95 97 99]
```